# Compile error in Grails xwiki plugin

Tags: grails, plugins, xwiki

I'm desperately trying to use the XWiki Grails plugin but had no luck so far. What I did:

- grails create-app xwikitest
- add "compile ":xwiki-rendering:1.0-RC3" in BuildConfig.groovy, plugin section.
- cd xwikitest
- grails
- run-app (no controller, empty web-app)
  Now grails answer with these errors:

`| Compiling 50 source files.
| Error Compilation error: startup failed:
Compile error during compilation with javac.
/home/pierre/.grails/2.2.0/projects/xwikitest/plugins/xwiki-rendering-1.0-RC3/src/java/com/monochromeroad/grails/plugins/xwiki/XWikiComponentManager.java:34: type parameters of T cannot be determined; no unique maximal instance exists for type variable T with upper bounds T,java.lang.Object
            return componentManager.getInstance(componentType, hint);
                                               ^
/home/pierre/.grails/2.2.0/projects/xwikitest/plugins/xwiki-rendering-1.0-RC3/src/java/com/monochromeroad/grails/plugins/xwiki/XWikiComponentManager.java:42: type parameters of T cannot be determined; no unique maximal instance exists for type variable T with upper bounds T,java.lang.Object
            return componentManager.getInstance(componentType);
                                               ^
2 errors`

1 error
| Error Error running script run-app: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.ScriptExitException (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Running Grails 2.2.0 under Fedora 14

I'm probably missing something obvious but can't find out by myself.
Any help appreciated, as this is driving crazy. TIA

Comment: I'm getting the same error.  It would seem that the author might have forgotten to include some dependency libraries that are required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the line `:xwiki-rendering:1.0-RC3` try doing a :

```
grails refresh-depencies
```

In your project root folder.

Comment: Thanks, Benoit. This effectively does the job but then, it fails on Xerces with message `Error running script run-app: org/apache/xerces/dom/DeferredElementNSImpl`. A quick search drove me to [this workaround](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9708). Does anybody have a real fix, as this isn't exactly user friendly?